# Whose resources does Maltego Footprint L3 exhaust? Mine or target's?

Tags: denial-of-service

Maltego Footprint L3 says: *This perform a level 3 (intense) footprint on a domain. It takes a while and it eats resources. Use with care.*

Whose resources do they refer to? My resources or the domain's resources? I'm allowed to gather all the information I can from a domain, but I don't want to cause a DoS on them.

Comment: Isn't this a question for Paterva support?

Answer (score 1):

One of the qualms I have with Maltego is that any information you search, gets proxied through them which means if you are searching for sensitive information, you have no idea what Paterva is doing with the information you search. Think about that for a moment. If you were an investigator, looking for something say critical to national security, there is a potential for abuse from anyone at Paterva, or anyone who would compromise their system. Enough tidbit information tho.

When you search for something via Maltego, it works like this:

```
you -> query -> Paterva -> digs out information on THEIR servers and relays it back to you
```

Depending on how much information you're searching, **YOUR** connection may not be able to handle the volume of data Paterva sends back to you. It's the "golf ball in the waterhose" affect. Where if they send you say 2Mbps of data per second, but you can only receive say 1Mbps, it will consume your connection.

Comment: Although not directly related to the OP's question but you can have your own transform server within the enterprise if you purchase the Professional version which won't leak any data to Paterva or any outside entity. The community version uses the community transform servers that is in control of Paterva.